# Expectation of absolute random variable and its relationship with absolute expectation value

Tags: expected-value, absolute-value

For any continuous random variable $X$, it is obvious that $|E X| \leq E|X|$.

My question is, what kind of distribution $P$, such that $X\sim P$ and satisfy $|E X| \geq c E|X|$ for some positive $c\in (0,1)$.

Comment: If $P(X\ge 0)=1$ or $P(X\le 0)=1$, and $0 <E[|X|] < \infty$ then $|E[X]| > cE[|X|]$ for all $c \in (0,1)$

Comment: If $E[X]=0$ and $0 <E[|X|] < \infty$  then $|E[X]| < cE[|X|]$ for all $c \in (0,1)$

Comment: That deals with positive random variables (and negative one) and those with zero expectation.  I suspect all others where $0 <E[|X|] < \infty$ have some small $c$ where the inequality is $>$ and some larger $c$ where the inequality is $<$.